# How to type this complex object idea?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this literal object:

```
const objectIdea = {
  form: {
    div: {
      attributes: {
        cssClasses: ["Container", "flex"],
      },
      h1: {
        attributes: {
          text: "Hello world 2!",
        },
      },
    },

    div: {
      h1: {
        text: "And so on."
      },
    },

    main: {
      h1: {
        attributes: {
          text: "Hello world!"
        }
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The idea es that the key represents and HTMLTag and it's value is another object which accepts an attributes key and another HTMLTag . The point of this ( i'm experimenting) is to automatically generate HTML Components from that object meaning that first Form it's the parent and continues with 3 childs div. The first div has an h1 tag and so on.  Object could be any length and any nested length but always should be:

```
 HTMLTag: { 
        attributes: HTMLTagAttributes,  // should infer this from it's parent         
        HTMLTag:  {      //is the child
                    attributes: HTMLTagAttributes,     // should infejr this from it's parent 
                    HTMLTag:  // I think you get the idea
}
```

I tried some stuff but nothing usefull to this problem.

```
interface IComponentObject<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap = keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> {
  T:{
    attributes: T
    
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you are not allowed to use same keys in an object. You are using two `divs` on a same level. Second of all, I believe you need to create a Tree data structure, it is closed to HTML than regular object

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible to create a structure, like yours.

There are two thinks you need to add:

- unique HTML Tags
- Recursive structure

Here is my code for this. Maybe this help.

```js
type HTMLTag = "div" | "form" | "p" // add more when needed

type UniqueHTMLTag = `${HTMLTag}#${string}` // make html tags unique, because same keys are not allowed

type HTMLDOM = {
    [key in UniqueHTMLTag]: {
        attributes: {
            "name": string
        }
        children: HTMLDOM
        // add more thinks
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the closest i get. This allow to have like "infinite" levels ? I mean if i create an HTML component i should have many different levels

Comment: Because it's recursive, you have as many levels and components per level as you want.